# sql search by field with type json

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mysql-8.0

There is a JSON column (info) in the database

Contains:

```js
{
    "time": 1,
    "conv_id": "2",
    "is_hook": false,
    "message": {
        "_text": "hello",
        "_type": 2,
        "_expansion": {
            "necessary": [id1, id2]
        }
    },
    "msg_type": 1,
    "from_user_expansion": null,
    "from_user_unique_name": "5"
}
```

I need to make a selection in the database, indicating a certain value in 'necessary'
Suppose we select all values from the database, the 'info' column in 'necessary' contains the id2 value

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? SQL Server, MYSQL, Oracle?

Comment: We use RDBMS  MYSQL

Comment: MySQL version??

Comment: mysql  Ver 8.0.25